# Изменение размеров областей сплиттером, либо overflow

Tags: html, css, bootstrap4

В общем есть задача сделать подобное расположение областей,
но с условием возможности изменения размеров каждой области. Как минимум верхние области должны менять по горизонтали, а нижняя по вертикали.
Как я понимаю bootstrap так не умеет, пробовал ещё split.js, но именной такой сетки где 2 области сверху и 1 снизу добиться не смог.
Может кто-то посоветовать что заюзать или было бы совсем круто - кусок кода, в котором этот вопрос был бы решен. Примеров пожих так и не смог найти.
Может вообще у меня подход неверный к решению вопроса

```css
.ls_resizable_all {
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<head>
  <title>TODO supply a title</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


</head>

<body>
  <div>




    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="  position: relative;">
        <div class="card ls_resizable_all">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
            <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="  position: relative;">
        <div class="card ls_resizable_all">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
            <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="card ls_resizable_all">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
            <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!--fragment end-->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем реализовал с помощью RickStrahl/jquery-resizable.